# CSS animation- translate up to a certain point when hovered

Tags: html, css, animation, hover, translate

I've just started with CSS animation, and what I want to happen is a circle moving from one end to another. I set it to translate to the right (when hovered) to a certain distance.

Problem is, whenever I change the size of the browser, it doesn't go where it's supposed to go. Instead, it goes all the way until it can't be seen anymore. How do I make it stop at a certain point in the div? Is there a solution in CSS or is Javascript or jQuery needed in this situation? Thank you in advance.

```css
html, body, #wrapper{
    min-width: 1000px;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    }

#wrapper{
    position: relative;
    }

body{
    padding: 50px;
    background-color: #f9f1dc;
    }

.one{
    background-color: #ffeffd;
    padding: 15px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    width: auto;
    }

.ball{
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    border-color: none;
    border-radius: 100%;
    background-color: #662a48;
    transition: transform 500ms ease-in-out; 
    }

.stay{
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    border-radius: 150px;
    }

.stay:hover .ball{
    transform: translateX(770%);
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    
        <head>
            <link href="css/ball-animation.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        </head>
        
        <body>
            <div class="one">
                <div id="wrapper">
                    <div class="stay">
                        <div class="ball"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
    
    </html>
```

Comment: See this: http://output.jsbin.com/gubolob

Comment: @MoshFeu but what if I only want the ball to move when the ball itself is hovered, not the wrapper? 
I tried making the wrapper the same size as the circle so that hopefully when hovered, it will move. But then only realizing that it depend on the width of the wrapper.

Comment: @MoshFeu I figured it out! Thank you so much for your help. I really appreciate it. I posted the final output in the answers portion.

Comment: My pleasure :) Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use vw units in animation not the "%"
The only fix You must do is to fit width of containers, and the animation. I try with this settings but it can be different

```css
html, body, #wrapper{
    width:80vw;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    }

#wrapper{
    position: relative;
    }

body{
    padding: 50px;
    background-color: #f9f1dc;
    }

.one{
    background-color: #ffeffd;
    padding: 15px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    width: auto;
    }

.ball{
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    border-color: none;
    border-radius: 100%;
    background-color: #662a48;
    transition: transform 500ms ease-in-out; 
    }

.stay{
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    border-radius: 150px;
    }

.stay:hover .ball{
    transform: translateX(50vw);
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    
        <head>
            <link href="css/ball-animation.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        </head>
        
        <body>
            <div class="one">
                <div id="wrapper">
                    <div class="stay">
                        <div class="ball"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
    
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

After understanding the answers offered, here is the final output.

```css
html, body, #wrapper{
  min-width: 1000px;
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#wrapper{
  position: relative;
  height: 150px;
}

body{
  padding: 50px;
  background-color: #f9f1dc;
}

.one{
  background-color: #ffeffd;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  width: auto;
}

.ball {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 150px;
  border-color: none;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: #662a48;
     position:absolute;
  left:0;
  transition: all 880ms ease-in-out; 
}

.stay {
  height:100%;
  width: 150px;
  border-radius: 150px;
 
}

.stay:hover .ball {
      left:100%;
      transform:translateX(-100%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link href="css/ball_anim.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="one">
      <div id="wrapper">
        <div class="stay">
          <div class="ball"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```